# Why this MySQL query with subselect and Max() wont work?

Tags: mysql

Why this MySQL query is not working?

With the Subselect I want to get only the last ID/price inserted.

```
select preco_id, centroide_produto_id, produto_id, preco_venda from precos A, cluster_copy3 CL
where A.preco_id = (select MAX(preco_id) from precos B where B.preco_id=A.preco_id ) 
and CL.centroide_produto_id = 9805
and A.produto_id=CL.similar_produto_id
```

Comment: is it giving any error

Comment: The subquery isn't limited to the rows that have matches with `cluster_copy3`.

Comment: Can you guys verify the logical? 
This way dont work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1af31/1
This way works: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5de63/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery is "correlated", that portion of the WHERE will always be true because the `MAX(X) WHERE X=X` is X. So you are getting **every** precos record associated with a cluster_copy3 record with 9805. Taking off the WHERE in the subquery should fix it, if I am guessing your desired result correctly.

I think this might be more what you need:

```
SELECT preco_id, centroide_produto_id, produto_id, preco_venda 
FROM precos AS A 
INNER JOIN cluster_copy3 AS CL ON A.produto_id=CL.similar_produto_id
WHERE A.preco_id = (
   SELECT MAX(preco_id) 
   FROM precos AS A1 
   INNER JOIN cluster_copy3 AS CL1 ON A1.produto_id=CL1.similar_produto_id
   WHERE and CL1.centroide_produto_id = 9805
)
```

or this should work as well:

```
SELECT preco_id, centroide_produto_id, produto_id, preco_venda
FROM precos AS A1 
INNER JOIN cluster_copy3 AS CL1 ON A1.produto_id=CL1.similar_produto_id
WHERE and CL1.centroide_produto_id = 9805
ORDER BY preco_id DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

Depending on the actual data, I am not sure which would be faster.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! When you say the WHERE in the subquery you men   where B.preco_id=A.preco_id right? I tried without and return 0 rows.

Comment: If you get 0 rows, that means the last precos did not have a 9805 cluster_copy3.

Comment: The problem isn't with the MySQL version. I think is a logical issue which I can't find :-(

Comment: I'm not saying anything about MySQL version. I am saying there is no combination of records that satisfies your WHERE, most likely because the MAX(preco_id) record does not associate to a cluser_copy3 record with a centroide_produto_id that has the value 9805. To find the last preco_id that satisfies that condition is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi Uueerdo! Can you please verify this SQL Fiddle example: This way dont work: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1af31/1 This way works: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5de63/4

Comment: Yes, the latter one, with preco_id = 4, does not have an association with a centroide_produto_id = 10.

Comment: You are the men! Thank you very much! The first one is what I extensively looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It should be not required where condition in sub query. Like this

```
select preco_id, centroide_produto_id, produto_id, preco_venda from precos A, cluster_copy3 CL
where A.preco_id = (select MAX(preco_id) from precos B  ) 
and CL.centroide_produto_id = 9805
and A.produto_id=CL.similar_produto_id
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! Without the WHERE in subquery, is returning 0 rows.

Comment: Check other condition